# Не запускается отладка Clion. Process finished with exit code 1

Tags: clion

При запуске дебага в clion программа не запускается и выводит в консоль "Process finished with exit code 1". Код:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define int long long

using namespace std;

int n;
vector<int> ans;

void gen(int pos){
    if (pos == n){
        for (auto i : ans){
            cout << i << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
        return ;
    }
    ans[pos] = 0;
    gen(pos+1);
    ans[pos] = 1;
    gen(pos+1);
}

signed main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    cout.tie(0);
    cin >> n;
    ans.resize(n);
    gen(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Брейкпоинт пробовал ставить везде: на строке **void gen**, на строке вызова функции **gen**, на строке **signed main** и на **cin>>n**. Везде один и тот же исход. При обычном же запуске все работает исправно. В конфигурации запуска стоит просто Debug

Comment: Брэндмауэр настроен?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, скорее всего нет. Можете сказать пожалуйста, что именно нужно настроить?

Comment: ОС какая у вас?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, arch linux